# Line Detection How to decide which lines to keep

Tags: opencv

I have a task where I need to detect power lines in the video. For example, here is an image taken from the video:
[image: original image]

Line is bright target in the video, so I used close operation to make it more clear. Then I used LSDDetect to detect lines. Then I get a collection of detected lines which are represented by end points. Here is the result:
[image: result]

But because the background is complex, I got many small lines that I don't want. I can filter most of them out by defining line angle(approximately 90 degree) and view field（x coordinate value range）. 
[image: filter result]

The problem is that the value is defined by me. How can I make the program calculate the proper angle and view field automatically? Or is there a better solution?

I'm new to opencv. Now I'm just using the library that opencv provides me, like the LSDDetect function, I don't know how they are implemented.

Comment: Please share few images for better understanding of the problem statement.

Comment: I added some pictures

Comment: I wouldn't stick with the angle, since it can vary, but you might consider using some morphological filters to remove the noise. Also, the lines you want to keep are mostly straight and big - you could also try to remove lines that are not straight (given a threshold, for instance) and have a minimum size. One other option would be the lines placement in the image - if you could guarantee they would cross the central part of the image, you could discart lines near the image's borders... You might also try to combine solutions, to get better results...

Comment: The LSDDetect method gives me a collection of lines, with two end points representing each line. So basically every line is straight. But I do have a length restriction and it has some effect. As for the morphological filters @LeonardoAlvesMachado mentioned, I used the close operation(dilate once then erode three times). The result is that the power lines seems brighter. Is that the right filter to take? And now I'm just keeping the rectangle area in the center(x coordinate range from 350 to 650). Is there a way to let the computer decide which area to keep?

Comment: In my opinion, if using the morphological filters the way you said allows you to differentiate the power lines from the others, you are at least in the right path. To decide which area to keep, why don't you use an sliding window approach - test if you find power lines in the center, if it don't find, try it on top/left, bottom-right, bottom-left, top-right (until you find what you want, or cover the whole image). The problem would be performance for worst case, but if most of the cases you find it in the center, it wouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: What's the expected output of line detection? Just a image with highlighted lines?